# java.sql.Timestamp is throwing error

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I am taking the current time using following method:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class TimeFormat
{
        public static Timestamp getCurrentDateAndTime()
        {
            String strFormat = new String("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat);
            java.util.Date theDate = new java.util.Date();
            theDate = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(formatter.format(theDate));
            Timestamp rtnTS = new Timestamp(theDate.getTime());
            return rtnTS;
        }
}
```

Now created another class as a data model:

```
public class InvoiceObject extends java.lang.Object implements Serializable
{
    public Integer mId;
    public Timestamp mTimeIssued;

    public InvoiceObject()
    {
            this.mId = new Long("0");
            Timestamp tempTime = TimeFormat.getCurrentDateAndTime(); //successful
        this.mTimeIssued = tempTime; //here throwing error
    }
}
```

Can't understand why it's throwing error during assign the current date

Comment: I *very* much doubt that a simple assignment is throwing an exception. However, the fact that you haven't even told us what the error is makes it hard to help you... (Why are you using `java.sql.Timestamp` when your data clearly *isn't* a full timestamp, anyway? If you've only got data to the level of `java.util.Date`, why not stick with that?)

Comment: I'm surprised that your method `getCurrentDateAndTime()` didn't ask you to either **throw** or **catch** a certain `ParseException`.

Comment: @R.J it has a throw and catch but before post here I have removed to make the space shorter

Comment: Sorry guys!!! my mistake. I haven't initialized the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mport java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TT {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static Timestamp getCurrentDateAndTime() throws Exception
    {
        String strFormat = new String("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat);
        java.util.Date theDate = new java.util.Date();
        theDate = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(formatter.format(theDate));
        Timestamp rtnTS = new Timestamp(theDate.getTime());
        return rtnTS;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InvoiceObject i=new InvoiceObject();
        System.out.println(i.getmTimeIssued());
        }

}
class InvoiceObject extends java.lang.Object implements Serializable
{
    public Integer mId;
    public Timestamp mTimeIssued;

    public InvoiceObject()
    {
           // this.mId = new Long("0");
            Timestamp tempTime;
            try {
                tempTime = TT.getCurrentDateAndTime();
                  this.mTimeIssued = tempTime;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //successful
       //here throwing error
    }
    public Timestamp getmTimeIssued() {
        return mTimeIssued;
    }
}
```